# How to merge two Word Document Objects in C# (not on file system level)?

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

i want to append one Word Document Object to another in my C# Code.

Is there any way to do this instantly with Word Interop Functions when i have both Documents as an Object?

I tried several approaches with Merge Function but this function expects filenames as strings and no objects. I don't want to save both documents and load them again.

```
//schematic version of my code:

doc_template = wordapp.Documents.Open(ref filedocA,
                 ref readOnly, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                 ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                 ref missing);          
doc_final = wordapp.Documents.Add(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
wordapp.Document tempdoc = null;

foreach (customer cust in dt_customers)
{
    tempdoc = doc_template;
    //Do some search and replace functions in tempdoc
    ...
    //here somehow the complete tempdoc should be appended to doc_final

}
```

doc_final should contain all the modified tempdoc from each customer

```
    //Update: Heres what i am doing now: Copying the contents within ranges
object start = tempdoc.Content.Start;
object end = tempdoc.Content.End; 
tempdoc.Range(ref start, ref end).Copy();
doc_final.Activate();
start = Destination.Content.End;
end = Destination.Content.End;


start = wordapp.ActiveDocument.Content.End - 1;
rng = Destination.Range(ref start, ref missing);
rng.Select();
rng.Paste();
```

But is there a better option than simple copy the contents of the documents?

Comment: [DocumentClass.Merge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.documentclass.merge).

Comment: Merge in that case does not append documents but mark differences, i stumbled across this function also couple of hours ago...

Comment: `Range.FormattedText` on both sides of the equation can work, although it will lose anything associated with the last paragraph mark (last section information). Or work with the Word Open XML (`Range.WordOpenXML` to get the content; `Range.InsertXML` to write the content but depending on the content YMMV). Beyond that, no, not with *opened* Word documents that haven't been saved to a file. If saved to a file, then `InsertFile` or the Master-/Sub-Document functionality would be the way to go.